# Last.fm API - Track Duration

Tags: php, time, format, last.fm

I'm using the Last.fm API and I stuck on something seemingly fairly simple.

One of the [responses](http://ws.audioscrobbler.com/2.0/?method=track.getinfo&api_key=b25b959554ed76058ac220b7b2e0a026&artist=cher&track=believe) is the duration. Which is returned as:

```
222000
```

But how do I format (in PHP) this to look like

```
MIN:SEC
3:42
```

Answer (score 8, accepted):

It looks like the duration is in milliseconds.  Just divide by 1000 to get the number of seconds.

Comment: In addition: echo date('i:s', $duration / 1000);

Comment: Wonderful. Thanks max and philippe :)